# How to add Logo Carousel in Hubspot?

Tags: hubspot

How to add this http://www.hubspot.com/style-guide/components#logo-carousel 
client logo carousel section on the website?

Comment: What problem are you having with implementing this?

Comment: I just need to know how to implement this Logo carousel section. its directly done on HS so if there any direct method by HS there i just no need to add custom modules

Comment: I think this is rather broad, and I am not sure it is even a programming question. On another note, please try to keep your questions succinct - we're not a forum, and it is quite normal for long-term users to tidy up posts. Please don't revert an edit unless it actually contradicts your original meaning.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about programming, and might be better on WebApps or SuperUser.

Comment: I have found a new thing HubDB , we can directly use HubDB as a database to add and fetch things, we can use HubDB  for this case too http://designers.hubspot.com/docs/tools/hubdb

Comment: @halfer its not off topic... we need add codes to add a logo carousel..

Answer (score 0):

We can do 3things

1 : we can use HubDB so we can use dynamic images  by calling hubl codes

```
{% set table = request.query_dict.get('company') %}
{{ table }}
{% set rows = hubdb_table_rows(xxxx,table ) %}
{% for row in rows %}
{% set hid = row.hs_id %}
{% if hid == table %}

<div class="span12">
    <div class="span8">
        <div><h1>{{ row.company_name }}</h1></div>
        <div>
{% if row.company_image %}
<img src="{{ row.company_image.url }}" alt="{{row.company_name }}">
{% endif %}
</div>
</div>

<div class="span4">
<div class="right-sidebar">
  <div><h3>{{ row.company_name }}</h1></div>
  <div>{{ row.company_description }}</div>
</div>   
</div>

</div>


{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

2 :  we can create a custom module, here we can't call dynamically but we can set the number

3 : Try this hubl code by using image slider module:

```
{% image_slider "custom_slider" export_to_template_context=True %}
 <div class="flexslider left">
    <ul class="slides">
  {% for slide in widget_data.custom_slider.slides %}
    <li><img src="{{ slide.img_src }}" alt="{{ slide.alt_text }}" class="subin" title="{{ slide.caption }}">
    <div class="meta">
    {{ slide.caption }}
    </div></li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```